# How to get RSU node coordinates in veins?

Tags: omnet++, veins

I'm used `Veins 5.0` in my simulation environment.

There are currently 4 RSU nodes in use. The `omnetpp.ini` code is as follows:

**omnetpp.ini**

```
*.fRSU[0].mobility.x = 125
*.fRSU[0].mobility.y = 125
*.fRSU[0].mobility.z = 3
...
```

Here is the C++ code for RSU:

**fRSUBehavior.cc**

```
posX = check_and_cast<BaseMobility*>(getSimulation() -> getModuleByPath("fRSU[0].mobility.x")) -> getPositionAt(simTime()).x;
posY = check_and_cast<BaseMobility*>(getSimulation() -> getModuleByPath("fRSU[0].mobility.y")) -> getPositionAt(simTime()).y;
EV << "X: " << posX << " Y: " << posY << std::endl;
```

In this file I want to get the location of that node. However, the value of the log output is always defined as 0.

How should I modify the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `getModuleByPath("fRSU[0].mobility.x"))` is unlikely to work. The module name is very likely `fRSU[0].mobility`, that is, it does not include the parameter name. Very likely, the `getModuleByPath` returns a Null pointer and, by chance, your program does not crash but you are instead reading somewhat sensible values.

Comment: Thanks your advice. you're right. So I solved the problem by substituting the `fRSU[0].mobility` argument in the code corresponding to `stage == 1`.